# Bootstrap modal body inline stye is not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

My bootrsap modal is not working properly when i am giving span float to the button  the body part is getting cut and even the width of the text box is not reducing and can you help me out with it and I even want this bootstrap modal is not coming on the center of the page.

Check my code:

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">CHECK</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <div class="modal-body" style="background-image: url('assets/images/banners/cat-banner-1.jpg');">

     <p> SHS Wallet </p>
     <form class="register-form outer-top-xs" role="form" method="post" action="order-details.php">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input"  width="10px" placeholder="Enter the amount to be added in the wallet"name="orderid" id="exampleOrderId1" >
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input" name="email" placeholder="Enter the Email ID for future refrence" >
  </div>
    <span style="float:right;"><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary ">Track</button></span>
 </form>

        </div>
     
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: Check the screen how its looks like]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your issue with the button not fitting. Also the modal is in the center of the screen. Check snippet below.

**EDIT: The modal is now vertically "centered" as well.**

Hope this helps!

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">CHECK</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="top:calc(50% - 170px)">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body" style="background-image: url('assets/images/banners/cat-banner-1.jpg');">

        <p> SHS Wallet </p>
        <form class="register-form outer-top-xs" role="form" method="post" action="order-details.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input" width="10px" placeholder="Enter the amount to be added in the wallet" name="orderid" id="exampleOrderId1">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input" name="email" placeholder="Enter the Email ID for future refrence">
          </div>
          <div style="text-align: right">
            <span><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary ">Track</button></span>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I added the screenshot please check what actually its looking on which i am trying to reduce the size of the textbox and the modal is in the center of the page

Comment: Its coming in the center of the screen only width wise

Comment: @PiyushSeofaceup I have updated my answer to include vertical centering. Hope this helps, and if this solves your problem do upvote and mark answer as Accepted in order to help future visitors to the post. Thanks!

Comment: @N.Ivanoa This what i a looking for.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Create new div with class=modal-footer after div with class=modal-body and move button html into it.

E.g.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <span class="pull-right"><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary">Track</button></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually modal is at centre of the screen by default.

Comment: I added the screenshot please check what actually its looking on which i am trying to reduce the size of the textbox and the modal is in the center of the page @mahesh

Comment: If you want to make bootstrap modal vertically center then refer this link https://codepen.io/dimbslmh/full/mKfCc
If you want to make modal size small then you can use modal-sm class. E.g. <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to remove the `style="float: right;"` and to give the div element the Bootstrap-Class `.pull-right`. (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)

Additionally you need to add an element with a clearfix. This class `.clearfix` has to be added to the div's parent element: form (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix)

By using those Bootstrap-plugins no problem should occur.

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">CHECK</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <div class="modal-body" style="background-image: url('assets/images/banners/cat-banner-1.jpg');">

     <p> SHS Wallet </p>
     <form class="register-form outer-top-xs clearfix" role="form" method="post" action="order-details.php">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input"  width="10px" placeholder="Enter the amount to be added in the wallet"name="orderid" id="exampleOrderId1" >
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input" name="email" placeholder="Enter the Email ID for future refrence" >
  </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
    <span><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary ">Track</button></span>
   </div>
  </form>

        </div>
     
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Unfortunately Bootstrap does not allow you to place the modal somewhere else. But you can set the left/right margin from the .modal-dialog element to do so:

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 30px 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

If you want the modal to be bigger or smaller use these classes: `modal-lg` for large or `modal-sm` for small

If you need vertical center use this:

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">CHECK</a>
<div class="modal fade"id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <div class="modal-body" style="background-image: url('assets/images/banners/cat-banner-1.jpg');">

     <p> SHS Wallet </p>
     <form class="register-form outer-top-xs clearfix" role="form" method="post" action="order-details.php">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input"  width="10px" placeholder="Enter the amount to be added in the wallet"name="orderid" id="exampleOrderId1" >
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input" name="email" placeholder="Enter the Email ID for future refrence" >
  </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
    <span><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary ">Track</button></span>
   </div>
  </form>

        </div>
     
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<style>
.modal-dialog { position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); width: 100%; max-width: 600px }
</style>
```

This uses the modern CSS Transform which is more flexible then hardcoding the position. As you use position:relative, you have to set width and max-width (value from bootstrap page)

Answer (score 0):

As your are using bootstrap modals.

Its very **easy**. Just add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the form as shown.

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">CHECK</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <div class="modal-body" style="background-image: url('assets/images/banners/cat-banner-1.jpg');">

     <p> SHS Wallet </p>
     <form class="register-form outer-top-xs" role="form" method="post" action="order-details.php">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input"  width="10px" placeholder="Enter the amount to be added in the wallet"name="orderid" id="exampleOrderId1" >
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input" name="email" placeholder="Enter the Email ID for future refrence" >
  </div>
    <span style="float:right;"><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary ">Track</button></span>
 </form>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
     
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">CHECK</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="float:left;width:100%;">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="float:left;width:100%;">
      
        <div class="modal-body" style="background-image: url('assets/images/banners/cat-banner-1.jpg');float:left;width:100%;">

     <p> SHS Wallet </p>
     <form class="register-form outer-top-xs" role="form" method="post" action="order-details.php">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input"  width="10px" placeholder="Enter the amount to be added in the wallet"name="orderid" id="exampleOrderId1" >
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control unicase-form-control text-input" name="email" placeholder="Enter the Email ID for future refrence" >
  </div>
    <div style="float:right;"><button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary ">Track</button></div>
 </form>

        </div>
     
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```